# The "Ask Question" button is misplaced

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

For the last few weeks, the "Ask Question" button is a bit of:

[image: screen shot]

Using Chrome 31.0.1650.63 on Linux

Comment: Not for me (Firefox on Linux and Windows). What browser you are using? Could it be some userscript / userstyle?

Comment: No repro on Chrome 31 on Win7.

Comment: It's likely because I have the correct font installed :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your screenshot, it looks like you've hit the font selection problem with the Roboto font. If you install Roboto under Linux, then when a site or program asks for Roboto, it gets "Roboto Medium" (which is quite heavyweight) instead of "Roboto Regular" (which looks normal). This is a problem with how the weights are set in the font files.

[This site has an explanation of how to change your font configuration to avoid the problem.](http://nileshgr.com/2013/02/24/configuring-roboto-font-in-linux) Once you've added the workaround you'll notice that ASE looks a lot 'lighter' in font terms, and much easier on the eye.

Comment: This is why these sites are so awesome. What an obscure and undiscoverable issue, yet someone knows the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What browser/OS are you using? It shows in the right place inside the grey bar for me on Win7 Sp1 x86 with Internet Explorer 9 and Firefox 26.